# I am trying to work, on this. Checking if this actually works?

Tags: java, confirmation

I am not sure if this actually works, so I just wanted to ask and confirm, if this is the right way to display the number and if I will get the output, which different date of births.

This program is a bit clumsy.

```
    int day = 0;
    int month = 00;
    int year = 1979;

    while(day<33 && month<14 && year<2005 && year>1978)
    {
        if(day==32)
        {
            day = 0;
        }

        if(month==13)
        {
            month = 00;
        }

        if(year==2004)
        {
            year = 1979;
        }

        String dob = new String(day+""+month+""+year);
        System.out.println(dob);
        if(dob=="2611983")
        {
            System.out.println("My birthday");
            break;
        }

        day++;
        month++;
        year++;
    }
```

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. Instead of `dob=="2611983"`, do `dob.equals("2611983")`

Comment: Are you getting some exception or unexpected output?

Comment: Alright, thank you @Hugo. Have a great day.

Comment: @Hugo, Sir thank you, again.

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you run it? 
Some forecast: It will not do what you might expect, because you are incrementing day, month and year in the same loop run. 
It also will loop forever, because you reset day, month and year inside your loop. 
It will, after a lot of loops, maybe hit a constellation that your birthday is met, but not like might think. 
Let it run and try to understand what happens.

Comment: So I have let it run, for quite quite a good load of time, but even after hitting, it doesn't do much. Thank, you though, I will work on it. Thank you again, SIr.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work properly because you are incrementing the day, the month and the year at the same time (ie you are not checking all the days) instead try doing this:

```
int day = 1;
int month = 1;
int year = 1979;
bool done=false;
while(!done)
{
 if(year==2004)
 {
        year = 1979;
 }
 while (month<13 && !done)
 {
    while (day<32 && !done)
    {
        String dob = new String(day+""+month+""+year);
        System.out.println(dob);
        if(dob.equals("2611983"))
        {
         System.out.println("My birthday");
         done=true;
        }
        day++;  
    }
    day=1;
    month++;    
 }
    month=1;
    year++;
}
```

Comment: Great, this a perfect code. Thank you! But I didn't quite understand the logic behind this, that why are you 'day=0' and 'month++', while in the other loop, 'month=0' and 'year++'. I am sorry, if the question was not a very considered one, but hope you can answer this to solve my query. Thank you for the code, and time. Have a great day.

Comment: @lafeo_007 I didn't notice it, thanks for pointing that out, I corrected it

Comment: No problem, in fact for the code above which I had typed had '0' for the day, and the month. Thank you again and have a great day.